# FileMaker Error: PDF could not be created on this disk

Tags: filemaker

I don't really know if this would be a good place to ask this question, but FileMaker's forums haven't really been all that helpful.  Our graphics department recently has been having issues with a script that they have been using for a few years now, and it just stopped working.  I know nothing about FileMaker's language and have never used it before, I've just been asked to try and get it figured out.

The version that we are using is Advanced Pro 18.

Here is a snapshot of the script that is being run

[image]

This is the error it produces:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: The most common cause of this error is invalid path. We don't see the contents of the field from which you take the path, so that's about all I can say at this point.

Comment: @michael.hor257k how could i see the contents of the field?

Comment: I suggest you ask this at one of the forums. I don't know which one you tried - usually they are very helpful (even overly helpful sometimes).

Comment: @michael.hor257k I will try asking in the forums.

Comment: Looks like you're only passing the file name to the Save as PDF in line 11. You need to supply the path also so add the path before the file name. Also the script debugger is really easy to use and with the Data viewer give you a clear view of the contents of the variables as you step through the script.

Comment: A file name is a also a (relative) file path.

Comment: Depending on script client/server/platform on execution the default path is different and there are areas that FileMaker cannot write to and you will get this error if you only provide a file name without a valid path.

Answer (score 1):

You should use full file path to set the $Filename variable in line 7 and line 18, like these:
in Windows:
Set Variable [$Filename; Value: "filewin:/DriveLetter:/DirectoryName/" & Log Book::calculate job # & ".pdf"]
or in Mac:
    Set Variable [$Filename; Value: "filemac:/VolumeName/DirectoryName/" & Log Book::calculate job # & ".pdf"]

Comment: Just note that if you use the function get(documentspath) or get(temporarypath) instead of the full path it will always set the correct path regardless of the operating system of the client.

Answer (score 0):

Check, if there is any font used in layout is missing in their computer.
If there are any fonts with upper case extension (.TTF), change it to lower case (.ttf)
It it is not the case, try Arial font for all the fields in the layout.

Comment: This should not have been really down-voted (was not me, btw ). The only issue with the answer is that it relates to a particular version of FileMaker which had an issue (15.0v2, I think). The correct answer was given by michael.hor257k in the comment to OP

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have enough space.
2. Make sure your pdf document with the same name is not open.
3. Reinstall your pdf reader.

Suggestion: You can make the script step more simple.

Answer (score 0):

One late additional note: make sure the filename is free of "prohibited" characters. If the string produced by Log Book::calculate job # included a "/" character, for example, you'd likely see the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `Save Records as PDF` script step, as the OP has, double-click it in the scripts workspace and check the path specification. If a disk is specified there, check that the disk name is correct and that the disk is available.

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally there can be a problem with the user's account or folder permissions and that can be worth investigating. Especially if it is working on one computer and not another.

In lines 7 & 18 I suggest you set the full path with `get(documentspath)` or `get(temporarypath)`. That will ensure a correct path for the operating system that the script is running on.
The result would look something like this:
Set Variable [$Filename; Value: get(documentspath) & Log Book::calculate job # & ".pdf"]

Also note that another cause for failure (there are many) is that there may be special characters, e.g. characters that are not allowed in a file path, in your  Log Book::calculate job field. If this field imports data from elsewhere it *may* import invisible characters that are not allowed.